# my submit button does not send my form with symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

by the way I realize a simple form with an email to inform, and click on send, but there when I click on my button to send my page is recharged only without any action. And my symfony toolbar tells me no error.

The purpose of this form is to recover a forgotten password

**Controller**

```
public function requestPassAction(Request $request, TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator = null)
{

    $email = $request->request->get('_username');
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
       ->add('username', EmailType::class, [
           'constraints' => [new Email(), new NotBlank()]
       ])
       ->getForm();
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)
               ->findOneBy(array('username' => $email));

       if (!$user) {
           return $this->redirectToRoute("renouvellement_pass");
       }

       $user->setToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
       $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \Datetime());
       $em->flush();
       return $this->redirectToRoute("login");
   }

   return $this->render('Resetting/request.html.twig', [
       'form' => $form->createView()
   ]);
```

}

**Twig**

```
{% extends "DoctixFrontBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    {{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_widget(form.username)}}
    <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

**Errors** with dump

```
 SecurityController.php on line 202:
   FormErrorIterator {#572 ▼
 -form: Form {#595 ▼
   -config: FormBuilder {#588 ▶}
   -parent: null
   -children: OrderedHashMap {#528 ▼
   -elements: array:1 [▶]
   -orderedKeys: array:1 [▶]
   -managedCursors: []
  }
 -errors: []
 -submitted: false
 -clickedButton: null
 -modelData: null
 -normData: null
 -viewData: null
 -extraData: []
 -transformationFailure: null
 -defaultDataSet: true
 -lockSetData: false
 }
-errors: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to customize how errors are rendered when a form is submitted with errors. The error messages for a field are rendered when you use the form_errors() helper:

Update your code add form error helper:

```
{% extends "DoctixFrontBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    {{form_start(form)}}
        {{form_widget(form.username)}}
        {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
        <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
    {{form_end(form)}}
{% endblock %}
```

Read more about [Symfony Customizing Error Output](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output)

or you could get error from controller:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

} else {
    dump($form->getErrors()); exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi @habibun,I tried your suggestions but symfony does not show me any error

Comment: if this is the case then I guess your form is not being submitted. check to submit option.

Comment: First, i try twig and nothing has changed. So i try controller and that display me a FormErrorIterato

Comment: I added the display of the dump in the controller.

Comment: see this line                -submitted: false

Comment: that means your form is not submitted.

Comment: Ok i fix that. Thanks